# Python SSLError - Any way to Hide Warning

Tags: python-3.x, request, warnings

I am wokirng on windows and with python3. 
I used requests module to get to a web page with this code-

`requests.get('https://github.com/')`

Then i got the `SSLError [SSL: CERTIFICATE VERIFY FAILED ]` error. Then i turned off the switch for SSL certificates check with `verify=False`.

```
import requests
requests.get('https://github.com/', verify=False)
```

And now it is browsing the site but returns a warning.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 847
    InsecureRequestWarning)
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding 
certificate verification is strongly advised. See: 
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
<Response [200]>
```

Now i am working with a script and i don't want to show this warning to user.I got a way to hide warning but i am not sure how to use it.

```
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

But this ignores all warnings and i just want to hide this 'InsecureRequestWarning' particularly. Please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 10):

So i got the solution to hide the warning. Here is what i did.

```
import warnings
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
requests.get('https://github.com/',verify=False)
```

And this thing solved my problem.

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly with the recent requests package.